# How can I reorder panes in Windows Terminal?

Tags: windows-terminal

I had my terminal set up with two panes. Like this:

`[A|B]`

I accidentally <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>'d a process running in the pane to the left, which results in the pane getting closed. When I split again, my new pane comes to the right. So that my setup becomes:

`[B|A]`

Is there anyway to restore the setup I had initially without cancelling the process running in B?

Comment: What about tabs? Can we reorder tabs using shortcuts?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you asked, this wasn't possible.

With Windows Terminal 1.12 however, this is possible with the `swapPane` actions. For more details, see: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/terminal/panes#swapping-panes-preview

The syntax for these actions is:

```json
{ "command": { "action": "swapPane", "direction": "down" } },
{ "command": { "action": "swapPane", "direction": "left" } },
{ "command": { "action": "swapPane", "direction": "right" } },
{ "command": { "action": "swapPane", "direction": "up" } },
{ "command": { "action": "swapPane", "direction": "previous" } },
{ "command": { "action": "swapPane", "direction": "previousInOrder" } },
{ "command": { "action": "swapPane", "direction": "nextInOrder" } }
```

But they should also be bound by default in the [Command Palette](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/terminal/command-palette), under the names "Swap Pane..."